# 12V Alternator charger using MOSFET with 3 x 12V output charging serial connected batteries ( 3 x 12V)

Tags: mosfet, dc, battery-charging, charger, diy

I am planning of building charger for trolling motor that will charge from single alternator 12VDC three serial connected batteries with three individual 12V outputs. This is something that is available on market (and I have Promariner ProSportHD) and most probably I will get DC as well, but I would like to try and make it by myself. I found already circuit with MOSFET and driver for charging two batteries but not in serial connection. Is anybody is able to draw or have already simple electrical drawings for this circle?

[image]

Batteries will be 120Ah charged with 2x60A alternators with 12V output.

Comment: Serial charging is unwise without at least 10% power BMS

Comment: A lot more information is needed. What is the battery capacity. What is the charging current and voltage available. An alternator does not supply pure DC, it is typically full wave rectified AC 3 phase. You found a MOSFET and driver, I can find that in the parts bin. What do you have, post links to perternante technical information on each of the devices.

Comment: Batteries will be 120Ah charged with 2x60A alternators with 12V output.